# How to create service from commandline and providing LanmanWorkstation password?

Tags: command-line, windows-10, windows-services

I'm creating a service:

```
sc create myservice binPath= "\\server\share\MyService.exe" DisplayName= "My service" start= delayed-auto depend= LanmanWorkstation obj= .\MYUSER password= MYPASS
[SC] CreateService SUCCESS
```

But when I attempt to start it, I get the following error:

```
sc start myservice
[SC] StartService FAILED 1069:

The service did not start due to a logon failure.
```

In order to fix this, I can go into Services (`services.msc`), right-click `myservice` and choose Properties, go into the "Log on" tab and re-enter the password manually. After having done this, I can successfully run `sc start myservice`.

**Is there some way I can avoid re-entering my password manually in the services.msc UI?**

Comment: What happens if you leave off the ".\" in the username?

Comment: @BenN That gives me a config error: `[SC] ChangeServiceConfig FAILED 1057:
The account name is invalid or does not exist, or the password is invalid for the account name specified.`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to creating/configuring the service to start with the specfic user you also need to provide the user with the "Run as a service" permission.

There are many ways how to do this, [this page](https://www.morgantechspace.com/2013/11/Set-or-Grant-Logon-As-A-Service-right-to-User.html) lists a few. I used the vbs script and it works fine.